# YouTube API v3 - Trying to get playlist IDs

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

I am using this code to get the playlist ids but it hangs on the Execute line. Does this code look right?

```
PlaylistsResource.ListRequest request = youtube.Playlists.List("id");
request.Mine = true;    
var PlayListResponse = request.Execute();
```

No error gets thrown. It just gets to the third line and never gets to the line after. I ran in debug mode and no error gets thrown.

Comment: _Does this code look right?_ Does this code looks **you** right? If it doesn't **why**?

Comment: How long does it hang? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: If you download the latest API and put this code in, you will get the same result as I am getting.